# How to transfer development database to production?

Tags: database, heroku, sinatra

I made a **Sinatra** app and now I'm trying to deploy it to **Heroku**. 
My app works with **PostgreSQL** database. There is data in my tables that I scraped during development. It is rendered just fine when I run it locally. However, when I deploy my app, my records do not get transferred. I know this behavior is normal, but I can't find how to transfer my records to production (database is set up correctly, you can add content through forms interactively).

This is my **environment.rb**:

```
configure :production, :development do
    db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/lakesare')
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    :host => db.host,
    :username => db.user,
    :password => db.password,
    :database => db.path[1..-1],
    :encoding => 'utf8'
    )
end
```

I have tried

```
heroku pg:push $my_db_name HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
```

and it ran successfully, but my records are still not present in production db. Did I do something wrong?
I would use *seeds.rb* kind of thing, but how to configure it in Sinatra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a seeds file you could do `heroku run ruby seeds.rb`. That is assuming that the seeds file is in the root of your application. You can run pretty much any command that you can run locally on the heroku servers by prepending it with `heroku run`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is to write a few functions that fill up your database, add them to **seeds.rb** in **db** folder, deploy this to Heroku and run

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
heroku run rake db:seed
```